# Удалите неиспользуемый код JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, делаю оптимизацию сайта на GooglePageSpeed и пишет

> Удалите неиспользуемый код JavaScript

Проблема в том, что **на ПК версии этого сообщения нет, а на мобильной есть**
Ругается он на файл app.min.js и **все, что в нем имеется - все задействовано в сайте
Если удалить хоть одну строчку кода, то все сломается.**
К слову показатели производительности на мобильной версии **40+** а на пк **85+**
Мобильная версия оптимизирована под устройство
Вообще не понимаю, как это исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на PageSpeed ***https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-cheboksary-go495-ru-news/063vt6un6b?form_factor=mobile***

Comment: Так как мы должны вам помочь?) Покажите Ваш код!

Comment: Там строчек кода в js 10к+, что мне именно скинуть?

Comment: как минимум ссылку на pagespeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это ваш личный проект - забейте на PageSpeed.

Если это аудит от СЕОшников, то два пути:
**а)** Cозвонитесь с ним и продемонстрируйте, что PageSpeed не показатель, отключите аналитику и покажите скорость загрузки сайта (она увеличится), добавьте скрипты и стили инлайново (она тоже увеличится), аргументируйте, что это бред.
**б)** Если СЕОшники так просто не отстают, выполните вариант **а** на момент проведения аудита и после верните как было.

Comment: а.1) Как аргумент - зайти на сайт гугла и запустить pagespeed. Даже там будет эта злосчастная плашка "Удалите неиспользуемый код" xD

Comment: Это не личный проект. Так если сайт не оптимизирован, то гугл его не будет продвигать в высокие списки на первых страницах, разве нет?

Comment: @Dima, скорее всего продвижение больше зависит от других факторов, вряд ли сами гугл больше смотрят на PageSpeed, т.к. первый комментарий реальный, даже у гугла показатель не 100% даже близко.